# Script doesn't contiinues after Exception with Try/Except:

Tags: python

I have the following function with a Try except in it to end the function if it generates any exception:

```
def bulk_insert(df, conn, table):
    try:
        print('Inserting dataframe into DB...')
        tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
        cols = ','.join(list(df.columns))
        aux = '(' + '%s,' * (len(tuples[0]) - 1) + '%s)'
        query = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(" + cols + ") VALUES " + aux
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cursor, query, tuples)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()

    except:
        print('Erro: ' + str(sys.exc_info()))
        pass
    
    return 'Done'
```

Unfortunately I'm having the following exception raised:

```
Erro: (<class 'psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat'>, InvalidDatetimeFormat('invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "None"\nLINE 1: ...\',\'Sistema\',\'CONSULTORA DE ATENDIMENTO - MISTA\',1,\'None\',5,\'...\n                                                             ^\n'), <traceback object at 0x7f1a4c08afc0>)
Inserting missing keys_elos...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "complete_sched.py", line 218, in <module>
    insert_elos_key(conn, table)  # Inserting elos_key
  File "complete_sched.py", line 151, in insert_elos_key
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE """+ table +""" es
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

After that the script does not continues.

Comment: try to add `finally`

Comment: Actually seems to execute but exception is being raised in a diffrent function... see the traceback. You have your erro printout but the error raised that kills your program is in insert_elos_key and not bulk_insert where you have shown.

Comment: @JasonChia actually you're right. I didn't noticed that.